# CQ5 get partly right results

Tags: jsp, xpath, aem

I'm trying to search in nodes via QueryBuilder/Query but it doesn't seem to work fine. I have following code method to search in about 6000 records.

```
public String searchRows(String search, int start, int length){
        Map<String, String> searchMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        searchMap.put("path", this.path);
        searchMap.put("fulltext", search);
        Query query = this.builder.createQuery(PredicateGroup.create(searchMap), this.session);
        query.setStart(start);
        query.setHitsPerPage(length);
        SearchResult result = query.getResult();
        //return result.getQueryStatement();
        StringBuilder sb = this.createBasicInfo(result.getTotalMatches());
        sb.append(this.toaaData(result));
        sb.append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

and I want to get results that just partly matches. For example I have node with these properties

```
Company   "My Drugstore Abc"
City      "My City"
Street    "Some Street"
```

If i try to search for "Abc" I get the right result but if I try to search for "drugstore" or "my" i get nothing. Also if I try to search "city" or "street" I get nothing... How can I solve this? I've tried to edit the search term like this

```
searchMap.put("fulltext", "*"+search+"*");
```

and this

```
searchMap.put("fulltext", "%"+search+"%");
```

but it still didn't work the way I need...

This is the Xpath i get from result.getQueryStatement();

```
/jcr:root/my/path//*[jcr:contains(., 'city')]
```

Thanks for any help

**Edit:** I've found out that this

```
searchMap.put("fulltext", "*"+search+"*");
```

works basically the way I need but it's so slow that the results may come back in bad order. The query takes 2-80ms without the asterisks but with them it's 1-6 seconds. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Doing wildcard searches using the following pattern is generally considered to be slow

```
/jcr:root/my/path//*[jcr:contains(., '*searchterm*')]
```

Better avoid these kind of queries. 
Doing fulltext searches without wildcards on certain properties is usually faster.

```
Doing jcr:contains(@jcr:PropertyName, 'searchterm')
```

You should have a look into Marcel Reuteggers presentation concerning efficient content structures and queries. Helps to understand how to avoid some performance critical query patterns.
http://de.slideshare.net/CQCON/prsentation-marcel-reutegger

Comment: Thanks for answer but how can I change the xpath using HashMap/QueryBuilder? I've tried this searchMap.put("type", "myType"); and this searchMap.put("property", "myProp"); but it didn't work...

Comment: Putting statements like jcr:contains(...) into the querybuilders Predicate map will not work. 
I'm afraid but to optimize the XPath query you would not get around creating the Query using an xpath statement.

Comment: How can I do that? I've tried to search it but the only thing I've found is creating query by QueryBuilder and Predicate map not just xpath statement...

Comment: By using the QueryManager 
QueryManager qm = session.getWorkspace().getQueryManager();

Query query = qm.createQuery(queryString, Query.XPATH);

See http://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-cq/using/querying-experience-manager-data-using.html, here is a nice example how to use it. Just avoid using the SQL2 dialect as it does not perform quite well at the moment.